# pytorch Neural Network "ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [482, 964]"

Tags: python, pytorch

I've created a pytorch Neural Network classification model with two binary output classes.  Class A is either 0 or 1 and Class B is either 0 or 1.  I've done this by modifying the code from a previous model that had a single binary output class. The model trains just fine.

My problem arises when I try to add a confusion matrix. It raises ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [482, 964].

I've isolated the source of the problem.

```
y_pred = model(X_test)
print (y_pred.shape)   # torch.Size([482, 2])
print (len(y_pred))    # 482

y_pred = y_pred.ge(.5).view(-1).cpu()

print (y_pred.shape)   # 964
print (len(y_pred))    # torch.Size([964])
```

y_pred = y_pred.ge(.5).view(-1).cpu()
this line has flattened the tensor from 482 x 2 into a 964 x 1.  Do I understand that correctly?

if so, how do I unflatten y_pred back into 482 x 2 tensor?

Thank you for taking the time to consider my problem. I'm trying to learn pytorch. it's like taking a sip of knowledge from a firehose. In other words, it can be overwhelming.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't avoid the flattening with `view(-1)`, then you can always unflatten by reshaping with:

```
>>> y_pred.view(-1, 2)
```